# a template specialization need

Tags: c++

This is very easy, I am stuck to figure out how that is used actually,

```
template<class C>
struct P{
};

template<> 
struct P<int>{};
```

Is there a real application for such specific specialization ?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell without any context.

Comment: Like you want to say that they are *actually* *both* empty?

Comment: While not a really good thing for other reasons, that is actually done inside the STL, `std::vector<bool>` is an specialization of the `std::vector<>` template

Answer (score 5):

while your specific example doesn't seem too interesting, template specialization is widely used. Here's an example:

```
template< class T >
struct StringConverter
{
  static std::string Convert( const T& )
  {
    //do some conversion from T to string using stringstream for instance
    //and return result
  }
}

template<>
struct StringConverter< std::string >
{
  static std::string Convert( const std::string& t )
  {
    //no need for conversion here!
    return t;
  }
}

//usage:
std::string a = StringConverter< int >::Convert( 5 ); //default impl
std::string b = StringConverter< std::string >::Convert( "b" ); //specialized
```

Comment: For a moment I read _wildly_ instead of _widely_. Seemed more appropriate ;-)